# jquery replaceWith problem

Tags: jquery, replacewith

I'm trying to replace some table elements while clicking the modify link,
actually it does replace, but the href attribute is not correct.
Is there anything wrong? Please help, thanks!!

HTML:

```
<html>
<head>
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <table id="department_list_table" border=1>           
        <tbody> 
            <tr id = 1>
                <td>department A</td>
                <td align="center"><a href = "#" onclick = "department_action('modify', 1, 'department A')">modify</a></td>
                <td align="center"><a href = "#" onclick = "department_action('delete', 1, 'department A')">delete</a></td>
            </tr>                
            <tr id = 2>
                <td>department B</td>
                <td align="center"><a href = "#" onclick = "department_action('modify', 2, 'department B')">modify</a></td>
                <td align="center"><a href = "#" onclick = "department_action('delete', 2, 'department B')">delete</a></td>
            </tr>                
        </tbody>
    </table>        
</body>
```

jQuery:

```
var id = 3;
var name = 'department C';
$("#department_list_table tbody tr#1").replaceWith(
    '<tr id =' + id + '>' +
    '<td>' + name + '</td>' +
    '<td align="center"><a href="#" onclick="department_action("modify",'+ id +',' + name + ')">modify</a></td>' +
    '<td align="center"><a href="#" onclick="department_action("delete",'+ id +',' + name + ')">delete</a></td>' +
    '</tr>');
```

Result in firebug:

```
<tr id="3">
<td>department C</td>
<td align="center">
**<a c)"="" modify",3,department="" onclick="department_action(" href="#">modify</a>**
</td>
<td align="center">
**<a c)"="" delete",3,department="" onclick="department_action(" href="#">delete</a>**
</td>
</tr>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're using double quotes when you should be using single quotes or escaped quotes:

```
onclick="department_action(\'modify\','+ i ...
```

Comment: THANK YOU VERY MUCH AlienWebguy!!

Answer (score 0):

The double quotes in `onclick` attribute is messing up the html string. A solution is to use `\'modify\'`, but you should consider attaching event handlers in JavaScript, using `$().click`. It generally makes the code more maintainable.